# Storing Avro schema in schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am using Confluent's JDBC connector to send data into Kafka in the Avro format.  I need to store this schema in the schema registry, but I'm not sure what format it accepts.  I've read the documentation [here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html#schemas), but it doesn't mention much.

I have tried this (taking the Avro output and pasting it in - for one int and one string field):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"     --data '{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"serial"}],"optional":false,"name":"test"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/view/versions
```

but I get the error: {"error_code":422,"message":"Unrecognized field: type"}

Answer (score 14):

The schema that you give as a JSON should start with a 'schema' key. The actual schema that you provide will be the *value* of the key **schema**.

So your request should look like this:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"     --data '{"schema" : "{\"type\":\"string\",\"fields\":[{\"type\":\"int64\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"id\"},{\"type\":\"string\",\"optional\":true,\"field\":\"serial\"}],\"optional\":false,\"name\":\"test\"}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/view/versions
```

I've made two other changes to the command:

- I've escaped each double quote within the value of the **schema** key.
- I've changed the struct data structure to string. I'm not sure why it isn't taking complex structures though.

Check out how they've modeled the schema [here](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/api.html), for the first POST request described in the documentation.

Comment: thanks, i think this is actually the correct answer, at least it helped me

Comment: If you're loading from a file like I was, you can use the --data @filename curl syntax, but make sure in that file contents, you're adding the schema key, and set the value as the schema you're loading, as well as escaping each double quote.  You can't simply throw in the raw schema in the file and load it.  Believe me, I spent 45 mins on this before I figured out what the problem was :)

Comment: I would like to add, that you might need to pre-process your schema file. If you have its JSON content formatted with all tabs and newlines, you might need to remove them. At least, before removing them I kept getting 500 response from the schema registry

Comment: Requiring modifying a perfectly good AVRO file by wrapping the contents as a String and escaping all quotes must make sense to somebody - wish I knew what purpose it serves other than to baffle and confuse

Answer (score 0):

First, do you need to store the schema in advance? If you use the JDBC connector with the Avro converter (which is part of the schema registry package), the JDBC connector will figure out the schema of the table from the database and register it for you. You will need to specify the converter in your KafkaConnect config file. You can use this as an example: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/config/connect-avro-standalone.properties

If you really want to register the schema yourself, there's some chance the issue is with the shell command - escaping JSON in shell is tricky. I installed Advanced Rest Client in Chrome and use that to work with the REST APIs of both schema registry and KafkaConnect.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question. Ofc what you write is correct, though.